# Android Lint issue in Eclipse after Java update

Tags: java, android, sdk

After updating Java and Android SDK for some reason I keep getting the following message:

```
'Running Android Lint' has encountered a problem.

 An internal error occured during: "Running Android Lint"
```

When I click on details, it says:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Running Android Lint".
com/android/sdklib/SdkVersionInfo
```

I changed target SDK to the latest version. Of course I could just turn off checking for errors. But how do I solve this issue properly?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, something [similar](http://code2care.org/pages/solution-running-android-lint-has-encountered-a-problem-nullpointerexception-error/) to your problem.

Not enough information, but looks some misconfiguration for versions of SDK in your project (targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion) and/or versions provided by your SDK which must be available in Project Structure.